# Take an amount of elements from ICollection

Tags: c#

How can you take an amount of elements from [`System.Collections.ICollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection) without knowing the collection type?

**Pseudo Code**

```
System.Collections.ICollection collection = new[] { 8, 9, 10, 12 };

collection = collection.Take(2);

/* collection == new[] { 8, 9 }; */
```

You would normally be able to do this with [`System.Linq.Take`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062) when the enumerable

Comment: `collection = collection.Take(2)` would not compile because `Take` returns a `IEnumerable<T>`, even if it was `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` you could still not re-assign it.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to `Cast<T>()` the values first. Linq (`Take()`) only works on generic types:

```
        System.Collections.ICollection collection = new[] { 8, 9, 10, 12 };

        collection = collection.Cast<int>().Take(2).ToList();

        /* collection == new[] { 8, 9 }; */
```

Comment: Or, better, use `ICollection<T>` in the first place (not clear whether or not there's a good reason not to from the question).

Comment: My objective was to do this with knowing the type.

Comment: Would it be safe to `.Cast<object>().Take(2)`?

Comment: If know that your collection **only** contains `int` values, then `Cast<int>()` is safe. If your collection also contains other types, and you're interested in the `int` values only (i.e. filter on `int` values), then use `OfType<int>()` instead

Comment: Yes, `Cast<object>()` will not fail, regardless of what type of objects are in the collection

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own non-generic extension method.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable Take(this IEnumerable @this, int take)
    {

        var enumerator = @this.GetEnumerator();
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < take && enumerator.MoveNext(); i++)
            {
                yield return enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            var disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;
            if(disposable != null)
                disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Collections.ICollection collection = new[] { 8, 9, 10, 12 };

        var result = collection.Take(2);
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: This is close, but IEnumerable can not be assigned to ICollection.

Comment: @roydukkey you state that in your question *"You would normally be able to do this with System.Linq.Take when the enumerable"*, but that is not true, you cannot assign the output of `Take` to a `ICollection<T>`, you could only assign it to a `IEnumerable<T>`. I took this fact to mean that your "psudocode example" did not care about the reassignment part, only the query part. If you really where comparing to `IEnumerable<T>` then your `collection` should be a `System.Collections.IEnumerable` not a `System.Collections.ICollection` to be compareable.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add one different approach

```
System.Collections.ICollection collection = new[] { 8, 9, 10, 12 };
var _collection = collection as IEnumerable<int>;
var result = _collection.Take(3);
```

Or

```
System.Collections.ICollection collection = new[] { 8, 9, 10, 12 };
var enunmerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
int count = 0;
while (enunmerator.MoveNext() && count < 3)
     {
                Console.WriteLine(enunmerator.Current);
                count++;
     }
```

Comment: `ICollection` inherits from `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<T>`.  Your cast is only valid because of the specific value you know you assigned, not for any given `ICollection` (even if it happens to only have integers).

Comment: @Servy Agree, Thanks for feedback, Edited.